# Google Charts remove white border around vAxis textPosition 'in' text on Bar Chart

Tags: google-visualization

How do I remove the white border around the vAxis textPosition 'in' text style on Google Charts Bar Chart?

My styling looks like this:

```
vAxis: { 'textPosition': 'in', 'textStyle': { color: 'black', 'stroke': 0 } },
```

I would like to have no surrounding white area around the black text within my coloured bars.

See this link: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/bubblechart

Notice how the Bubbles have text inside them with a white border around them. I want to remove this border so that the black text sits directly over the bubble colour with no border around the black text.

I have tried lots of combinations such as:

```
'textStyle': { color: 'black', 'stroke': 0 }
'textStyle': { color: 'black', 'strokeWidth': 0 }
'textStyle': { color: 'black', 'border': 0 }
'textStyle': { color: 'black', 'border': 'none' }
```

Nothing I have tried makes any difference. I still have the white border around the text.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an undocumented 'auraColor' option that applies to several, if not all, 'textStyle' options.  For example,

```
textStyle: { auraColor: 'white' }
```

Setting it to 'none' will remove it.